# Capture strings from the 3rd line using regexp_substr

Tags: regex, oracle

I need help to capture all the strings in the 3rd line using REGEXP_SUBSTR. The string in the third line varies. I tried the below pattern but it capture other lines I need the 3rd line only, (abc|rty|qer) doesn’t work as this string varies.

Pattern: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(Datasource,’(abc|rty|qer).*’)`

Datasource:

```
abc def ghi
pqr stu vwx
abc dfg qrt
zxc qet qwr

qep rty djf
ety fjf fjf
rty fgg tyy
rty tyy ffg

qwr tyy yyy
qer ggg rrf
qer ttg ggg
prw rjr trt
```

Desired Result:

```
abc dfg qrt
rty fgg tyy
qer ttg ggg
```

Comment: Differ how.? first i thought because if numbers but the first has none, so what is the pattern?

Comment: My main concern is how to capture all the strings in the 3rd line only irrespective of the data.

Comment: as there is no discernible pattern. regular expressions are no good, so you nust explain why the ried and than you can use

Comment: You posted 4 rows by 4 rows by 4 rows in what you called "datasource". Is all of that contents of a single row, or are these 3 rows (each of them containing strings that span 4 rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are slower than normal string functions. You can simply use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` to find the third line:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         datasource,
         INSTR(datasource, CHR(10), 1, 2) + 1,
         INSTR(datasource, CHR(10), 1, 3) - INSTR(datasource, CHR(10), 1, 2)
       ) AS third_line
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (datasource) AS
SELECT 'abc def ghi
pqr stu vwx
abc dfg qrt
zxc qet qwr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'qep rty djf
ety fjf fjf
rty fgg tyy
rty tyy ffg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'qwr tyy yyy
qer ggg rrf
qer ttg ggg
prw rjr trt' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| THIRD_LINE |
| --- |
| abc dfg qrt |
| rty fgg tyy |
| qer ttg ggg |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7tNPV7Bp)

Comment: Hi @MT0, it works but I replaced it to chr(13), I don’t know why it doesn’t work with chr(10). But thank you for the idea, really appreciate it indeed.

Comment: @ClintMohamed `CHR(13)` is carriage return (CR, or `\r` in regular expressions), `CHR(10)` is line feed (LF, or `\n` in regex). Linux editors usually only use LF as the new line character, windows editors use two characters CRLF; however, I've sometimes come across editors that only use LF (last week it was MS Excel that confused me by only using LF and not CRLF).

Comment: The most important thing is that the idea is there. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing a multiline string in a column and you want the third line.

You want to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

For a multiline string use the match parameter 'm'. The dot doesn't match the new line by default, so the start '^' and the end '$' refer to a single line. You want the third one, hence:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '^.*$', 1, 3, 'm')
from mytable;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/5Cb90_M1

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need `regex`, just indexing. Imagining your data source as

```
data_source = readLines(textConnection('abc def ghi
pqr stu vwx
abc dfg qrt
zxc qet qwr

qep rty djf
ety fjf fjf
rty fgg tyy
rty tyy ffg

qwr tyy yyy
qer ggg rrf
qer ttg ggg
prw rjr trt'))[c(1:4, 6:9, 11:14)] # to take out `\n` newlines

array(data_source, dim = c(4,3,1))
, , 1

     [,1]          [,2]          [,3]         
[1,] "abc def ghi" "qep rty djf" "qwr tyy yyy"
[2,] "pqr stu vwx" "ety fjf fjf" "qer ggg rrf"
[3,] "abc dfg qrt" "rty fgg tyy" "qer ttg ggg"
[4,] "zxc qet qwr" "rty tyy ffg" "prw rjr trt"

# check if we're on the right track with this array, appears so
data_arr = array(data_source, dim = c(4,3,1))

as.matrix(data_arr[3, , ], ncol = 1)
     [,1]         
[1,] "abc dfg qrt"
[2,] "rty fgg tyy"
[3,] "qer ttg ggg"
```

So, indexing rather than regex, where applicable.

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: As first presented in an `R` thread, there was nothing to suggest it was an Oracle query that was desired, though perhaps the result of one,  so I just took it as a text object. Otherwise, the presented Oracle solutions both strictly use indexing, and not regex, whatever their Oracle functions are called. All cases here are indexing based solutions for which regex would be a misnomer, except in the Oracle environment.

Comment: The [revisions to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76987215/revisions) do not mention `R` in any edit to the question.

Comment: Noted, perhaps it is my `regex` filter, but came up in my `[r]` questions...